# Start applications via windows task scheduler

Tags: console, c#, windows-task-scheduler

I have a **C#** **console** application which starts the some of windows desktop applications say for example notepad, Skype. I have created a basic task in windows task scheduler and then gave **when i log on** as **trigger** and pointed to my **console exe**. But the application not getting triggered **when i log on**.

Below was my code in **void main**

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe");
Process.Start(info);
ProcessStartInfo process2 = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Skype\\Phone\\Skype");
Process.Start(process2);
```

Let me know if i was unclear/Misunderstood.

Comment: I have edited the code.

Comment: Show what you have configured in your Task Manager's task. I suppose you have not enabled interaction with desktop. Check your processes with Process Explorer after logon. Check your event log in Computer management.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the exe works fine when not called from the Task Scheduler (TS)?
Try creating a ".cmd" or ".bat" file.
Add your console exe and execute ("start") from inside the new batch file.

Example - Task Scheduler batch file to start skype - replace with your console exe:

```
@echo off
start "My EXE Console Window Title" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\skype.exe"
```

Call the batch file (not exe) from your TS. Does it work now?

Which also brings up an aside from your direct question: You do realize you can just [write a batch file](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/create-windows-batch-files/) to start those applications when you login (from TS) - why have another exe do it? Or you could even just add win apps individually to the TS? OR you could simply add to [startup](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/run-program-automatically-windows-starts#1TC=windows-7).

Consult http://ss64.com/nt/start.html for some batch 'start' options to call EXE or "start /?" for command help in CMD.

Comment: Yes when debugging the code works fine . And also i don't have any idea accomplishing this task in optimal way so that only i prefered exe.

Comment: Edited answer a bit. Try the batch file method to start your exe..

Comment: I have created a batch file with the code you have given and pointed that in Task Scheduler but i opens the cmd instead of application

Comment: My feeling is the exe (since it's console only) needs to execute CMD and TS has issue with that. you could also try adding to TS using your exe as a parameter to cmd. = "cmd c:\path\your.exe"

Comment: ^ "I have created a batch file.."  -> Yes it will open cmd to execute the batch file. Try this- open cmd/console. run the batch file manually. does it start your exe? If not something isn't right in batch file.

Comment: echo off
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\skype"

This was the code when i give start bat file path in cmd it creates two more cmd . Don't know what went wrong

Comment: Too many comments -Go here https://gist.github.com/bmatthewshea/45b5192d1c57dbaa116e